# Integer literal '255' overflows when stored into 'Int8'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have the following code and i get the following error. **Integer literal '255' overflows when stored into 'Int8'**

```
func decodeIDArrayItem(index:Int, tokenArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>){

    var value = tokenArray[index * 4] & 0xFF
    value <<= 8;
    value |= tokenArray [index * 4 + 1] & 0xFF
    value <<= 8;
    value |= tokenArray [index * 4 + 2] & 0xFF
    value <<= 8;
    value |= tokenArray [index * 4 + 3] & 0xFF

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Int8` should be between -128 to 127. `UInt8` should be between 0 and 255, is that what you are looking for instead? Define `value` as UInt32?

Comment: yes I tried and did not work but because i was doing:  UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4] & 0xFF) when I had to UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4]) & 0xFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func decodeIDArrayItem(index:Int, tokenArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) -> UInt32{

    var value:UInt32 = UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4]) & 0xFF

    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(tokenArray [index * 4 + 1]) & 0xFF
    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(tokenArray [index * 4 + 2]) & 0xFF
    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(tokenArray [index * 4 + 3]) & 0xFF


    return value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're trying to extract 8 bit data into 32Bit format. You're getting issues because signed char. Any way try with UInt32, it will work fine. 
I hope below code will help you.

```
func decodeIDArrayItem(index:Int, tokenArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) -> UInt32{

    // convert into 4 byte
    // tokenArray[index * 4] of type UInt8 formate
    var value:UInt32
    let byte1 : UInt32 = UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4]) // 0 index
    let byte2 : UInt32 = UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4 + 1])<<8 // 1 index
    let byte3 : UInt32 = UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4 + 2])<<16 // 2 index
    let byte4 : UInt32 = UInt32(tokenArray[index * 4 + 2])<<32 // 3 index

    value = byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4

     return value



}
```

Answer (score 0):

haha! this worked for me
`Int8(0xff & 0xff)`

nice little hack